# Need to add grid line in CameraX for android

Tags: android, android-camerax

Need to add the grids to the CameraX API in the Custome Camera module. We have used PreviewView to show the Camera stream. Also created the CustomePreviewView extended from PreviewView to draw the grid lines.but the are visible for the moment until the Camera preview start Streaming.

public class CustomePreviewView extends PreviewView {

```
public CustomePreviewView(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setWillNotDraw(false);
}

public CustomePreviewView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setWillNotDraw(false);
}

public CustomePreviewView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.setWillNotDraw(false);
}

public CustomePreviewView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    this.setWillNotDraw(false);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    int screenHeight = (int) (metrics.heightPixels*0.9);

    //  Set paint options
    Paint paint =  new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));

    canvas.drawLine((screenWidth/3)*2,0,(screenWidth/3)*2,screenHeight,paint);
    canvas.drawLine((screenWidth/3),0,(screenWidth/3),screenHeight,paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0,(screenHeight/3)*2,screenWidth,(screenHeight/3)*2,paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0,(screenHeight/3),screenWidth,(screenHeight/3),paint);
}
```

}

and following is setPreview use case.

```
private Preview setPreview() {
        Rational aspectRatio = new Rational(previewView.getWidth(), previewView.getHeight());
        Size screen = new Size(previewView.getWidth(), previewView.getHeight()); //size of the scree
        if(preview!=null) {
            preview.clear();
        }
        preview = new Preview.Builder().setTargetResolution(screen).setTargetAspectRatioCustom(aspectRatio).build();
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.createSurfaceProvider());
        return preview;
    }
```

Comment: Does this happen with both of `PreviewView`'s [modes](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView.ImplementationMode), `ImplementationMode.TextureView` and `ImplementationMode.Surfaceview`?

Comment: Not mentioned any implementation mode..But one new update, now i have created the custome grid layout to apply the grid and placed that below PreviewView layout in Xml file and its work..but don't  know it is ideal to use like this .. may be  ..need to work on above approach.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView)-

> If PreviewView uses a SurfaceView to display the preview stream, be
> careful when overlapping a View that's initially not visible (either
> INVISIBLE or GONE) on top of it. When the SurfaceView is attached to
> the display window, it calls requestTransparentRegion which requests a
> computation of the transparent regions on the display. At this point,
> the View isn't visible, causing the overlapped region between the
> SurfaceView and the View to be considered transparent. Later if the
> View becomes visible, it will not be displayed on top of SurfaceView.
> A way around this is to call requestTransparentRegion right after
> making the View visible, or initially hiding the View by setting its
> opacity to 0, then setting it to 1.0F to show it.